# Using Popen with special characters in args

Tags: python, subprocess, postgis, popen

I'm using Python's Subprocess, specifically the Popen constructor.
I have a command of the form:

```
command = "raster2pgsql -tags /vsicurl/url_containing_= ..."
```

This command contains the symbol "=" at some parts. It seems that when I run the following code:

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd=r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.2\bin")
    out, err = p.communicate(timeout=10)
except:
    print("Error occured (probably timed out)")
finally:
    print("out: {}, err: {}".format(out.decode('utf-8'), err.decode('utf-8')))
```

My error messages indicates that the "=" signs in the command have all been treated as tags and configurations for the command.
I tried wrapping the command around in quotes such as

```
command = """raster2pgsql -tags "/vsicurl/url_containing_= ..." """
```

But it's still the same. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Do you need `shell=True`? Debugging might be easier with splitting manually and passing a list.